# sound not playing on real device

Tags: ipad, sdk, audio, audiotoolbox

I'm trying to play a sound in the iPad using this code:

```
-(void)playSound:(NSString *)filename {
    SystemSoundID soundID;
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filename ofType:@"wav"];    


    if (path) { 

        UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_AmbientSound;    

        AudioSessionSetProperty (
                                 kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory,                        
                                 sizeof (sessionCategory),                                   
                                 &sessionCategory                                            
                                 );

        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path],&soundID);
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundID);

    }
}
```

Sound is playing right in the simulator but it doesn't work on the real device (no, it's not muted :-) )

Comment: How long (in seconds) is your sound file? Is it LPCM-encoded? Does it work if you use `AVAudioPlayer` instead of `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound`?

Comment: No, I've played it also through AVAudioPlayer and it doesn't work either. The file is really short, like 2-3 seconds. How can I know if it's LPCM-encoded?

Comment: Run `file(1)` on your file, e.g. `file sound.wav` in Terminal.app.

Answer (score 0):

Check the file extension for case sensitivity, is it "WAV" or "Wav"... instead of "wav"
Or check your filename for the same reason.

That could solve your problem.